# kendoComboBox editor in kendoGrid always returns [object Object] the first time only

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I'm having a weird problem that only occurs in some cases, and I have no idea why. I have an editable kendoGrid, a column in which has a kendoComboBox editor. The first time I add a new row and pick an option, the column always shows `[object Object]`, but if I pick again the second time it shows the correct value. It's always only the first pick that shows `[object Object]`. I tried catching it with a template to log the incorrect value, it's just a string, not an object.

I have pretty much the same method of editing as in another grid, on another page, and that one works fine. I copied the editor code for this one and adjusted the field names. Here's the offending column:

```
{
    field: "Customer_Name",
    title: "Customer Name",
    width: 220,
    editor: function(container, options){
        var data = o.data.CustomerList;
        $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoComboBox({
                    autoWidth: true,
                    dataSource: data,
                    dataTextField: 'Customer_Name',
                    dataValueField: 'Customer_Name'
                });
    },
},
```

`o.data.CustomerList` is from an ajax call, I verified that it contains the correct array of objects.

I'm using Kendo UI v2017.1.118

Comment: What is the Customer_Name field configuration in the Grid's dataSource schema? Do you have a default value and is it an object? See how it is done here: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

Comment: Check your field in the model. If the value of the string is null, you'll get this behaviour. Change it to `String.Empty`.

Comment: @SJaka I resolved my issue by your comments. its work like charm :) Thanks.